# Make emergency fixes on production environment. Azure Devops

Tags: azure-devops, continuous-integration, continuous-deployment

I have three environments on azure devops. 
dev, test and prod.

I have a bug in prod, and the fixes for that bug is in dev. But I don't want to push everything that is in dev to test and then prod because it's not ready.

How can I push only one commit to production?

Comment: You shouldn't just fix the bug in your dev branch, you should create a new branch for this fix.

Comment: @LittleMygler Not get your response for several days, would you please share your latest information about this issue? If you have any concern, feel free to share it here.

Comment: Yeah i got my answer! I marked it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That`s depends on your branching strategy. If you have separate branch for each env, you can just cherry pick your commit from history: [Copy changes with cherry-pick](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/cherry-pick?view=azure-devops&tabs=visual-studio)